# Ansible inventory variable undefined

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I've defined a variable in my inventory file, but i get error variable is undefined when using it in play condition.

inventory.yml:

```
[nodes]
node1 ....
node1 ....

[cluster:children]
nodes

[cluster:vars]
somevar=False

testvar=value
```

playbook.yml:

```
- include: setup_whatever.yml
  when: "testvar == 'value'"
```

run it with

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory
```

here is the error message i get

```
ERROR! The conditional check 'testvar == 'value'' failed. The error was: ERROR! error while evaluating conditional (testvar == 'value'): ERROR! 'testvar' is undefined
```

ansible version: 2.0.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade your Ansible version to a modern one.

- Ansible 2.0.0.2 (yours)

```
ERROR! The conditional check 'testvar == 'value'' failed. The error was:
ERROR! error while evaluating conditional (testvar == 'value'):
ERROR! 'testvar' is undefined
```

- Ansible 2.1.3.0 (also outdated!)

```
PLAY [nodes]  
\*******************************************************************

TASK [debug]  
\*******************************************************************  
ok: [node1] => {  
　 "msg": "Hello world!"  
}
```